# paintComponent clears the JPanel when paint an image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have this code:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Draw {

Object block;

public Draw(JFrame frame, Object object) {
    this.block = object;

    JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3869097656854760151L;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            try {
                g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File(object.getTexture())), object.getX(), object.getY(), object.getWidth(),
                        object.getHeight(), null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Image '" + object.getTexture() + "' could not be found!");
            }
        }
    };

    frame.add(pane);
}
}
```

and I call the class here:

```
package game;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame {

private final int X_SIZE = new vena.util.Computer().screenWidth();
private final int Y_SIZE = new vena.util.Computer().screenHeight();

public Frame() {
    JFrame f = new vena.util.Frame().frame("2D Game", X_SIZE - X_SIZE   /   5,  Y_SIZE - Y_SIZE / 5, true, false, false,
            "res/icon.png");

    new Draw(f, new Object(0, 0, 100, 100, "grass"));
    new Draw(f, new Object(100, 0, 100, 100, "grass"));

    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame();
}
}
```

It renders when I call the image with

```
new Draw(f, new Object(0, 0, 100, 100, "grass"));
```

But when I call the image another time, next to it

```
new Draw(f, new Object(100, 0, 100, 100, "grass"));
```

it only renders the second image, and removes the first one. I have noticed that this doesn't occur when I call g.drawImage() twice in the paintComponent method. Is there a way so that I can call the Draw class as many times as I want, without clearing the JPanel?

Comment: It looks like you never set a [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for your frame. That means that the second panel will simply replace the first one when it's added. Use an appropriate layout to position the two panels like you want.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be calling `ImageIO.read` inside your paint method. That's going to have terrible performance. Read the image in when you create the object, and then reuse the same instance each time `paintComponent` gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default layout manager of the content pane of a frame is the BorderLayout. When you add components to a BorderLayout and you don't specify a constraint the component goes to the CENTER. Only the last component added can be displayed in the CENTER.

If you want multiple components on the frame then you can change the layout manager. Try

```
f.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
```

to see the difference.

> I have noticed that this doesn't occur when I call g.drawImage() twice in the paintComponent method.

Yes, if you are trying to paint images at specific locations on the frame then you should really be overriding paintComponent() to paint each image.

Comment: I did that, and now it's just drawing a tiny black box at the center-top of the frame. Any idea why?

Comment: @Vena The FlowLayout respects the preferred size of the panel (which is basically 10x10 since you didn't add any components to the panel). So you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` of the panel to return the size of the image. Or the easier solution is to just use  JLabel with an ImageIcon to display your image. There is no need for the custom panel. I really don't know what your requirement is.

Comment: Where do I put the overridden getPreferredSize? Also, do you mean that I should create an ImageIcon, set that ImageIcon to a JLabel, put the JLabel on a JPanel and then the JPanel on the JFrame? Isn't that harder and more time consuming?

Comment: @Vena, Yes, that is what I mean. No it is not harder because you are using classes of the JDK and an not reinventing the wheel by trying to paint an image on a panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Hmm. I created a new JLabel with the ImageIcon as a parameter. Then I set it the size to the size of the object is passed, as well as the location. After that I did 'new Frame().p.add(label);', but it isn't working. (p is a JPanel with FlowLayout). The frame isn't appearing, unless I comment out the 'new Frame().p.add(label);'. Any idea why?

Comment: @Vena, I can't guess what you are doing based on o brief verbal description I provided you with a working example. Download the working example and modify it for your actual requirement.

Comment: Never mind. It works now. I tried changing the JPanel to static, and accessed it using Frame.p, instead of new Frame().p. Also, I set the layoutmanager of the JPanel to null. Thank you for your help. Also sorry if I was unclear.